# How to write form to has_many association without nested_form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a **Patient** model. And I want be able as a Patient adds multiple **Doctors**.

Usually how I do it by creates with nested_form for Patient(without any of his attributes)

```
# @patient = current_patient
= simple_nested_form_for @patient do |form|
  = form.simple_fields_for :doctors, @patient.doctors do |f|
    = f.input :first_name
    = f.input :last_name
  = form.link_to_add :add, :doctors
  = form.button :submit
```

And I am using **PatientsController** **#update** action to add and remove doctors from them.

I have already one **PatientsController** with edit action to edit Patient information.

I think right controller to add multiple **Doctors** to **Patient** should be **DoctorsController**. But this will not work with form above which always update **Patient** object.

So how this form should looks like? What is correct pattern for that?

Gem: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Ryan's railscast [#196 Nested Model Form (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) where he shows what you are trying to do.  Basically, instead of Patient and Doctors he uses Question and Answers. Jump to minute 10:00 to see it in action and confirm that is what you are looking for.  The correct controller is Patients in this example.